# Macro will only create hyperlink in debug mode

Tags: vba, excel

This is a macro that will search all cells in all worksheets in all of the workbooks contained in a single directory. Everything works as advertised except for the add hyperlink method, which does work if I repeatedly mash F8.

How can I edit the macro so the hyperlink portion works?

```
'Search all workbooks in a folder for string
Sub SearchWorkbooks()
Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim strSearch As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim wOut As Worksheet
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

strSearch = "Capacitor"
strPath = "C:\!Source"

Set wOut = Worksheets.Add
Lrow = 1
With wOut
    .Name = "Results"
    .Cells(Lrow, 1) = "Workbook"
    .Cells(Lrow, 2) = "Worksheet"
    .Cells(Lrow, 3) = "Cell"
    .Cells(Lrow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
    .Cells(Lrow, 5) = "Link"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
          (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
          UpdateLinks:=0, _
          ReadOnly:=True, _
          AddToMRU:=False)

        For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
            Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            End If
            Do
                If rFound Is Nothing Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    Lrow = Lrow + 1
                    .Cells(Lrow, 1) = wbk.Name
                    .Cells(Lrow, 2) = wks.Name
                    .Cells(Lrow, 3) = rFound.Address
                    .Cells(Lrow, 4) = rFound.Value

                    'This is the line that does not work
                    'well it actually works in debug mode but not in real time
                    wks.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(Lrow, 5), Address:=wbk.FullName, SubAddress:= _
                                    wks.Name & "!" & rFound.Address, TextToDisplay:="Link"

                End If
                Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
            Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
        Next

        wbk.Close (False)
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
    .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
'MsgBox "Done"    

ExitHandler:
Set wOut = Nothing
Set wks = Nothing
Set wbk = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: It sounds like a timing related issue (which makes no sense), try commenting out the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` line and run it. That may slow it enough that it will work.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't work. It definitely feels like a timing issue because  when driven slowly it works perfect.

Comment: When you're using multiple worksheet you shouldn't use the implicit reference to a worksheet. Try adding the worksheet reference to your `Cells()` call out like `wks.Cells(......)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the worksheet reference to your `Cells()` call out like `wks.Cells(......)`

Comment: That was it! Not only that but it also fixed another annoyance where sometimes it would write to the wrong workbook. Thank you so much!